# Sverchok generating random points on faces facing upwords

Tags: normals, sverchok

I'm trying to scatter random points on a mesh, this points should be scattered only on faces that have their normals facing upwords (z axis)...
how can i create something like this? I?ve been fidling around for a while and i couldn't figure it out nor find any help online :(

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is not answerable at the moment for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you tell us only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button under the post. Editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: there is node random points on mesh